# conditionally disable a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, link-to

In my Rails app, I want to enable people to delete projects only once they've entered in the title of the project:

[image]

My current "Delete Button" link is defined as follows:

```
   <%= link_to "Delete Project", @project, :method=> :delete, :class=>"btn btn-danger disabled delete_project_btn"%>
```

Why the styling works correctly, the user can still click the link even when the button has the disabled class.

I'd like to only be able to delete the project when the user has added the name of the project:

```
$('.delete_project_btn').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
      console.log('preventing link click');
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{

    }
  });

    $('.delete_project_text_area').blur(function(){
      if($(this).val() == <%=@project.title%>){
        $('.delete_project_btn').removeClass('disabled');
      }else{
        if(!$('.delete_project_btn').hasClass('disabled')){
          $('.delete_project_btn').addClass('disabled');  
        }
      }
    });
```

I am able to see the log message "preventing link click" when I click the "Delete Project" button without having entered the name of the project, but it is still deleting the project.

**How can I conditionally disable a link_to?**

Comment: For good measure, did you also try doing `return false;` after the `e.preventDefault();`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the original link_to and replacing it with a dummy button, only adding the link once the user has typed the full title of the project:

```
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger delete_project_btn disabled">Delete Project</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.delete_project_text_area').bind('input propertychange', function(){
      if($(this).val() == "<%=@project.title%>"){
        $('.delete_project_btn').replaceWith('<%=link_to "Delete Project", @project, :method=> :delete, :class=>"btn btn-danger delete_project_btn"%>');
      }else{
        if(!$('.delete_project_btn').hasClass('disabled')){
          $('.delete_project_btn').replaceWith('<button class="btn btn-danger delete_project_btn disabled">Delete Project</button>');
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```